# Что делать если не собирается игра на unity?

Tags: unity3d

Я в Unity новичок да и в StackOverFlow недавно зарегался. При нажатии на Build&Run выдает звук ошибки (как на динамиках в Windows 10) и не собирает ничего. А в свою первую игру уж очень хочется поиграть. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Открой консоль, где высвечивается весь ход сборки. Посмотри какие ошибки там и сюда скинь. Мы посмотрим и посоветуем что сделать.

Comment: Я открыл и увидел, что все скрипты сломаны. Они написаны правильно, но No mono behavior scripts in the file, or their names do not match fail name. ХЗ что это за ошибка, но просто копирую и вставляя свой код опят попробую решить

Comment: Так не хз-кай, а ищи в интернете решение по тексту этому. Сделай перевод. Если не знаешь значение, всегда переводи. Сделай скриншот вывода и скинь

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1079331/no-monobehavior-scripts-in-the-file-or-their-names.html вот сразу же решение есть готовое в интернете.

Comment: Спасибо вам люди добрые